# Disable renaming a PDF Document

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a pdf that i have encrypted using adobe acrobat. Is it possible to also stop people from renaming the document internal and external to my company

i have tried searching Google but have not been able to find an answer for this it also doesn't have anything in the help pages on adobe. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You mean changing the file name? Or what do exactly do you want to prevent?

Comment: yes i want to prevent people changing the document name that are external to my company

Comment: No. You can't prevent the users from changing the `Filename`. You don't have control over their filesystem. (Even read-only files are re-nameable) In the PDF however there is a `Title` which they can't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file that contains a PDF document is no different to the OS than any other file.  The name of the file is set and altered by OS means.  You can't restrict changes from within the file.

Comment: so your saying you cannot stop people from renaming any file unless it is an open file that is in use?

Comment: @ben950 Depending on your OS, you can rename even files that are in use.

Answer (score 4):

Renaming a file is not a feature of a PDF or reader that can be disabled, it's a feature of the file system. As long as you control the file system, you can prevent renaming the file, most commonly by disabling write access. Your document doesn't get to control someone else's file system. If you are handing out copies, they can be renamed by whoever has them.